# How to attach a wood moulding trim around a backsplash

Tags: trim, backsplash

I'm installing a backsplash and trying to hide the ugly edges at the countertop ends. My wife and I decided on a wood moulding type trim, but I'm stuck on the best way to attach it to the drywall around the tiles.

The trim itself is 11/16" wide and 5/16" deep and would be cut to a maximum length of about 19". Should I use a glue like Liquid Nails since it's so small, or would a more "permanent" solution like tiny finishing nails do better?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Construction adhesive would certainly do the job, but it would destroy the drywall when you remove it.

I'd use silicone caulk as both the adhesive and the caulk to the countertop. It'll be rock solid, and if you ever need to remove it you may be able to do so without ripping paper off the drywall. Just put 2 or 3 quarter-sized dabs along the back. They'll flatten out to create nice wide attachment pads.

Be sure to completely paint or seal the trim, front and back, before attaching. Water is a tough nemesis for wood.

Comment: +1 And as to the OP's last question, finishing nails in drywall would definitely not hold, and tacking at the few stud points (if they lined up) would allow too many gaps.  In any event, it needs a sealer as you said.

Comment: Silicone works good but it doesn't grab as fast as a good construction adhesive.  Silicone is optimal for this but you need to put some weight against the trim for a good deal of time to make sure it lays flat.